# Run django app with apache

Tags: python, django, apache, wamp

I create a django app and run it with runserver command and it works.But i want to run it with apache so i install wampserver 2.5 with apache 2.4.9 .After that download mod_wsgi‑3.5.ap24.win‑amd64‑py3.4.zip from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi) and put it in apache modules folder and add this codes to httpd.conf :

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIPythonHome E:/software/Python34
WSGIPythonPath E:/software/Python34/python.exe
WSGIScriptAlias /ms "E:/software/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/htdocs/mysite/mod.wsgi.py"
Alias /ms "E:/software/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/htdocs/mysite"
```

and put my django app to mysite folder.but now wamp not run and remain yellow.
Note that this is my application's version:
--  python 3.4  --  Django 1.7  --  wamp 2.5  --  apache 2.4.9  --
and this is codes inside mod.wsgi.py:

```
import os, sys

path = r'E:\software\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\htdocs\mysite'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings' 

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

sorry for my terrible English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just followed [these steps](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/frameworks/django-apache-and-modwsgi-on-centos-5) and its worked for me.
Hope that help you too.

Answer (score 0):

following links will help you out.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-django-with-mod_wsgi-and-apache-with-a-virtualenv-python-environment-on-a-debian-vps

Comment: Link only answers are not encouraged on SO as links can change/get deleted. Please add some actual information to the answer or it will probably get removed.